# background image for a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a background for a div, but I want to make the size of the background fixed and the size of the div is variable! So when div width is decreased to half, I need to show only the first half of the image! and not resize it to fit it!
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default a background image will remain fixed at its actual size. It sounds like you may have the `background-size` property applied to the element, can you provide your code in a Fiddle or similar?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Comment: I can't see anything in the Result pane, but yes you've got `background-size: 100%` applied which will force the image to the full width of its container.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

I've just set the "background-position: 0px 0px;".